# magento merge attribute with categories and select only categories

Tags: magento, attributes, categories

In magento at time to upload product one by one, we have to select first attribute set and then select categories, we want to fix attribute set for each categories and at time to upload product we have only to select categories

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about to import product by csv. i think it will be more flexible with csv file.
because if you want to fix attribute set with some categories. you need to modify code and you have to define categories name in code file. now problem is that if you will add new category it's compulsory to define in code too.

so you have to manage with csv. you can define 'category' and 'attribute_set' column side by side.